# What could be the cause of too much fluctuations of validation loss and accuracy?

Tags: neural-networks, cross-validation, conv-neural-network

[image]

I am doing a binary-classification problem and I have 7600 images, 3800 for each class. I am wondering why the accuracy and loss plots look like these. Is this fine? or is this a symptom of some mistake or something else

Comment: Try batch normalization. Also, I assume that you already normalized the samples.